# How do I convert a non-Generic IList to IList<T>?

Tags: c#

I have class that wants an `IList<T>`, but I have a `Systems.Collection.IList`, coming from an NHibernate quere.

I want to create a method that converts it to an `IList<T>`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 85):

If you're sure that all of the elements inherit from T (or whatever type you're using)

```
IList<T> myList = nonGenericList.Cast<T>().ToList();
```

If you're not sure:

```
IList<T> myList = nonGenericList.OfType<T>().ToList();
```

Of course, you will need the System.Linq namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 6):

`Cast` and `OfType` return `IEnumerable<T>` implemetnations, not `IList<T>` implementations, so they wouldn't be useful to you.

Calling .`Cast<T>().ToList` will result in an extra copy of the list, which may have adverse performance implications.

A better (IMHO) approach would be to just create a wrapper class and do the conversion on the fly. You want something like this:

```
class ListWrapper<T> : IList<T>
{
    private IList m_wrapped;

    //implement all the IList<T> methods ontop of m_wrapped, doing casts
    //or throwing not supported exceptions where appropriate.
    //You can implement 'GetEnumerator()' using iterators. See the docs for 
    //yield return for details
}
```

That will have the advantage of not create another copy of the entire list.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use Linq, like `list.OfType<T>()` or `.Cast<T>()`

Answer (score 4):

Fredrick is correct. But Nhibernate also has an option to return multiple result sets.
For example:

```
  IList multiResults = session.CreateMultiCriteria()
                .Add(pageCriteria)
                .Add(countCriteria)
                .List();
```

In the above call there isn't an option to return a typed list. So it has to be casted as mentioned above, like this:

```
 IList<T> results = ((IList)multiResults[0]).Cast<T>().ToList();
            IList counts = (IList)multiResults[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you achieve that NHibernate returns you an IList ?
The ICriteria interface defines an `List<T>` method ...

Comment: Yes you can! Just use var result = Session.CreateCriteria(....).List<T>() instead og .List().

Comment: @stiank81: it was a rethorical question. ;)

Comment: Well - I understood that ;-) Just adding a comment with the details together my +1 in joy after just learning this from you..

Comment: There is no List<T> with CreateMultiCriteria.List(). that I see.

Answer (score 1):

Frederik is correct, NHibernate already does this.

```
var data = query.List<MyType>();
```

This would result in an IList of the type you specified.  In this case `IList<MyType>`.

Answer (score -2):

No need for use Linq in this case (OfType() or .Cast).
NHibernate implementation is enough.

You just have to use:

```
var results= query.List<YourType>();
```

Instead of

```
var results= query.List<>();
```

Comment: IList doesn't have List method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist?view=net-6.0#methods