# Convert from System.Collections.Generic.IList<object> to System.Collections.IList

Tags: c#, collections

I have implemented the following class:

```
class LazyList<T> : IList<T>
{
    public LazyList(IEnumerable<T> enumerable) { }
}
```

I need to use this class with non-generic legacy `System.Collections`. I have solved half of the problem by using `IEnumerable.Cast<object>()` as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/776407/2109230/.

However, I need to cast `LazyList<T>` to non-generic `IList` to complete the refactor process. How can I achieve this?

##### UPDATE 1:

LazyList basically helps me refactor a method that returns IList after iterating an IDataReader. I use data returned from this method to send some updates over WebSocket. The point is to send data constantly, not after processing the entire IDataReader. I have used yield return to return a lazy IEnumerable, but other methods require the refactored method to return IList. So, I came up with the idea of LazyList.

There are actually two methods, one returning `IList<T>`, which I have refactored successfully, and another returning `IList`. I wanted to see if there is a simpler way to refactor the version returning IList, without implementing non-generic LazyList. However, I did that and it wasn't that bad.

Comment: So implement both `IList<T>` and `IList`.

Comment: That's horrible because I have to duplicate methods, but that's my best solution too.

Comment: Many of them can be implemented in terms of the generic version and done in one line using expression-bodied syntax.

Comment: Duplicating methods is just part of the game. [`List<>`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs) does it, for `IList`, `ICollection`, and even `IEnumerator`. In your case, it can at least mostly be one-liner pass-through methods.

Comment: It's not horrible. It's the proper way to do it. If a class doesn't implement an interface then how do you expect to access an instance of that class via that interface? If `ILIst<T>` extended `IList` then you'd be fine but it doesn't, so you have to implement it yourself, just like many standard .NET classes do, e.g. `List<T>`.

Comment: The problem is that, if I add the following non-generic constructor `LazyList(IEnumerable enumerable)`, it will break the implementation of the generic methods since the underlying list will be IList<object>.

Comment: @MatrixRonny _"if I add the following non-generic constructor"_ - there is no constructor in the interface, so you should not add it.

Comment: An `IList` isn't an `IList<object>`, it's a completely different interface. If you want to implement both (why?) you'll have to implement both their members. Do you *really* need `IList` though? That's a pre-2007 interface, used when generics didn't exist

Comment: At this point, you should be thinking about composition. If you have one interface and you need a different one, *adapt it* with a wrapper class. Trying to implement `IList<T>` for multiple `T`s on a single class will be problematic, and it starts at the `IEnumerable` iimplementation because you have to figure out which `T` it will enumerate.

Comment: Since you have *undisclosed* concerns about standard approach I'd recommend to reconcile that problem with the question - please [edit] it to clarify why you can't implement both interfaces. So far feels a bit opinion-based to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the pattern the `List<T>` does - implement both interfaces and use [explicit interface implementations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) to remove some duplication (see the [source code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs,21)) and limit the exposed contract. Something to get you started:

```cs
class LazyList<T> : IList<T>, IList
{
    public LazyList(IEnumerable<T> enumerable) { }
  
    public void Add(T item) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public int Count { get; }

    public int Add(object? item)
    {
        Add((T)item!); // call to the generic implementation
        return Count - 1;
    }

    int IList.IndexOf(object? item)
    {
        if (IsCompatibleObject(item))
        {
            return IndexOf((T)item!); // call to generic 
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    
    private static bool IsCompatibleObject(object? value) => (value is T) || (value == null && default(T) == null);

   // ...
}
```

Comment: Surprising that you still decided to suggest it as an answer when [OP said](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2109230/matrixronny) "That's horrible because I have to duplicate methods, but that's my best solution too." While I agree with that answer it does not really feel like it answers OP concerns (whatever those are)

Comment: In this case, I need the following constructor too: `public LazyList(IEnumerable enumerable) { }`. However, the IList<T> implementation with T other than object is not compatible with that constructor, so it doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Panagiotis Kanavos stating that: "An `IList` isn't an `IList<object>`, it's a completely different interface". In addition, accessing `LazyList<T>[index]` created from a non-generic `IEnumerable`, will throw a conversion error if T is initialized with anything else than object.

I ended up with another class implementing `IList` using the original `LazyList<T>`, to avoid casting object to T:

```
public class LazyList : IList
{
    LazyList<object> _lazyList;

    public LazyList(IEnumerable enumerable)
    {
        _lazyList = new LazyList<object>(enumerable.Cast<object>());
    }
}
```

I did duplicate the methods, but it seems there is no other way.